# Assigning class variables through iteration of a string in Python

Tags: python, iteration, dynamic-variables

I have the problem of wanting to assign variable names from string. I understand this is called dynamically assigning variable names, but solutions on other pages I don't think apply to this situation, or I simply don't understand.

I'm trying to turn a string into a chess board, whereby the board is a list of lists. Each list a row, each item its respective column.

```
def splitString(string, length):
    """Split string into lengths on n."""
    return [string[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(string), length)]


def colourFromCase(letter):
    """Work out if a letter is uppercase, therefore white."""
    if letter.isupper():
        return 'white'
    else:
        return 'black'


def buildBoard(height, width):
    """Build a board."""
    global rows
    rows = []
    board = 'CNBHKDRNCPPPPPPPPPpppppppppcnrdkhbnc'
    split = splitString(board, width)
    for n in split[0]:
        className = eval(str(ABBRIVIATIONS[(n.upper())]) +
                         '(' + colourFromCase(n) + ')
```

The focus being on the buildBoard function - the last for loop. I need to make a variable with the name of n which is a class variable.

My first guess would be:

```
eval(n) = eval(str(ABBRIVIATIONS[(n.upper())]) +
               '(' + colourFromCase(n) + ')
```

I understand I've not made this incredibly clear. I don't think eval or exec is the way to go, but I don't see how I could use dictionaries or getattr() to do this since after I'm going to add the variable to a board with board.append()

Comment: Dont do this. Is is almost never necessary. Use a dictionary instead to store string/value pairs. The use of `eval` should have raised red flags.

Comment: By any chance could you link me to some place with examples of this, I have no clue what to google...

Comment: Do you know what a dictionary (`{}`) in Python is?

Comment: I do, but I don't know how I can use it for this use...

Comment: You're trying to dynamically create variables. Say you want to create a variable called `something2` holding `3`. Why not just add the string `"something2"` as a key to a dictionary with `3` as it's value?

Comment: I'm wanting to make a variable for example with: P = Pawn('White')

Comment: And then this variable P goes into a list. Are you suggesting rather than adding P you add the dictionary pointer?

Comment: You want to have a variable called `P` that holds a `Pawn("white")`? Just make that a key/value pair: `{"P": Pawn("white")}`, then add "P" to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a dictionary map holding references to your class types, e.g.:

```py
FIGURES = {"B": BType, "C": CType, "D": DType, "H": HType, "K": KType, "N": NType, "R": RType}

def buildBoard(height, width):
    """Build a board."""
    global rows
    rows = []
    board = 'CNBHKDRNCPPPPPPPPPpppppppppcnrdkhbnc'
    split = splitString(board, width)
    for n in split[0]:
        figure = FIGURES[n.upper()](colourFromCase(n))
        # etc.
```

Of course, make sure you have all possible figures referenced in the `FIGURES` dictionary and make sure they are pointing to what you're storing now in `ABBRIVIATIONS`. Also, make sure your *figure* classes accept white/black string as their init argument.